# How to save object detection output?

Tags: python, object-detection, yolo, yolov4

I wrote a code which runs the object detection(yolo) against bunch of images and writes output of the object detection along with the image into different folders based on the predicted classes. It basically classifies images based on the content into different folders. I created the folders based on the classID. Here is the code:

```
files=glob.glob(data_path)  
for f1 in files:
    image=cv2.imread(f1)

    # construct a blob from the input image and then perform a forward
    # pass of the YOLO object detector, giving us our bounding boxes and
    # associated probabilities
    blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(image, 1 / 255.0, (416, 416),
                                 swapRB=True, crop=False)
    net.setInput(blob)
    layerOutputs = net.forward(ln)

    # loop over each of the layer outputs
    for output in layerOutputs:
         # loop over each of the detections
         for detection in output:
              # extract the class ID and confidence (i.e., probability) of
              # the current object detection
              scores = detection[5:]
              classID = np.argmax(scores)
              confidence = scores[classID]
              box = detection[0:4]
              (centerX, centerY, width, height) = box.astype("int")
              # get upper left corner
              x = int(centerX - (width / 2))
              y = int(centerY - (height / 2))
              
              # update our list of bounding box coordinates, confidences,
              # and class IDs
              boxes.append([x, y, int(width), int(height)])
              confidences.append(float(confidence))
              classIDs.append(classID)

              # filter out weak predictions by ensuring the detected
              # probability is greater than the minimum probability
              if confidence > args["confidence"]:
                  # extract the bounding box coordinates
                  (x, y) = (boxes[i][0], boxes[i][1])
                  (w, h) = (boxes[i][2], boxes[i][3])

                  # draw a bounding box rectangle and label on the image
                  color = [int(c) for c in COLORS[classIDs[i]]]
                  cv2.rectangle(image, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), color, 2)
                  text = "{}: {:.4f}".format(LABELS[classIDs[i]], confidences[i])
                  cv2.putText(image, text, (x, y - 5), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,
                              0.5, color, 2)
                  # write output files
                  class_dir = os.path.join('/path to folder/', LABELS[classID])
                  if not os.path.exists(class_dir):
                      os.makedirs(class_dir)
                  path = os.path.join(class_dir, f1.split('/')[-1][:-4])
                  cv2.imwrite(path + '.jpeg', image)
                  with open((path + '.txt'), 'a+') as f:
                      f.write(str(classID) + ' ' + str(box[0]) + ' ' + str(box[1]) + ' ' + str(box[2]) + ' ' + str(box[3]) + '\n')
```

I would like to know which images did not have any object of interest to be detected.

**My question:** sometimes object detection does not detect any objects in the image,so it just ignores those images and does not save them. How do I modify this code to write those images into a "unclassified" folder?

Comment: Can you provide the full function where you're trying to save the image.
There might be some implicit conditional where you might only be getting the images where there is a detected object.

Comment: The other parts are feedforward yolo, I updated the code.

Comment: Your `if:` branch handles images that have been classified. You just need an `else:` branch that has the `cv2.imwrite()` call to write the images to the other directory, using code very similar to what you already have for writing the classified images.

Comment: I am not sure, how do you mean exactly? could you please modify the code so that I can understand it? thanks